# open a web link from different text in a text view

Tags: ios, url, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have an iOS app in which the text from a text view is too long to fit.  So I am trying to link the web address to the text in the textView.
Here is what I have.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"azgovernor.gov/engage/form/contact-governor-ducey"];
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Email Governor"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value:URL range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
govemail.attributedText = str;
```

The Email Governor shows up in the TextView as hyperlink(blue link) and when I touch it, it reacts.

However, the link doesn't respond and I get this message:

Could not find any actions for URL `azgovernor.gov/engage/form/contact-governor-ducey` without any result.

If I put this address into Safari it opens the page fine.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: That's not a URL. It's just a string. URLs begin with a scheme such as `http` or `mailto`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"http://azgovernor.gov/engage/form/contact-governor-ducey"];
govemail.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
govemail.editable = NO;
govemail.attributedText = str;
```